# (quickblox) How to add people to a chat dialog?

Tags: ios, swift, chat, quickblox

I am implementing a group chat but i can add people

Here is my code

```
var dialog_toupdate = QBChatDialog(dialogID: dialog.ID)
    println( dialog.ID )
var selecteduser = ["the id"]

dialog_toupdate.setPushOccupantsIDs(selecteduser)

QBRequest.updateDialog(dialog_toupdate, successBlock: { (response, dialog) -> Void in


   //some staff




    }, errorBlock: { (errr:QBResponse!) -> Void in


        println(errr.error.description)

})
```

and i get this error:

> Error reasons:
>       code = "null" message = "Resource not found"

Answer (score 3):

1. Please update to the latest QB SDK v2.3.0.4
2. In order to send messages from QBChatDialog instance that you have locally created you should do the following:

   1-1 chat:

   - Have dialogID set

   Group chat

   - set occupants IDs
   - roomJID **(!)**

   Without roomJID that you have received from a server you can not send messages

*Please note*:
 You can not convert 1-1 chat into group chat. You should create new group chat with occupants.

Comment: i can send message and receive message i create the group directly with member but if i try to add more people it does not work!

Comment: Kader, please provide us with full console log for further investigation.

Comment: 2015-09-03 14:43:20.127 buyzar[539:173535] Response headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 44;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 03 Sep 2015 11:43:19 GMT";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
    Status = "404 Not Found";
    "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
    "X-Request-Id" = 1c2736778b8ad69a5e66763740566921;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.003427";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}

Comment: the error  error code  ** [QBResponse], status: 404**

Comment: the code you provided doesn't contain the ID. Please, have DialogID set as replied above.

Comment: @kaderkabore I am getting this same header in response when i am calling tag=dev api. And its killing me. Did you get the answer. Please let me know as soon as you get the solution

Comment: I found that the dialog was nil on my case.I will strongly recommed to use qmservices if you are not already using.It make things easy.https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-services-ios.let me know if i can help more.

Comment: Fixed link https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-services-ios , services offers you convenient way to work with Quickblox, we support services up to date